# Does $\sqrt[n]{b_1^n+...+b_m^n}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, roots

As very first task in our analysis I class we got the following task which gives (only) 1 of 16 points. I add the points in order to calculate the needed effort to solve this task...

So let $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$ and $a_n:=\sqrt[n]{b_1^n+...+b_m^n}$, with $b_i\geq 0$ and $i=(1,...,m)$
We have to prove if this sequence converges and determine the limit (by using $\epsilon$ definition).

After running a simple R simulation I found out, that this sequence seems to converge against **m**.

As I have learned so far, the first step is to determine an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ so that $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, n\geq N : |a_n-m|<\epsilon$, but while searching for that $N$ I began to struggle.
$|a_n-m|=|\sqrt[n]{b_1^n+...+b_m^n}-m| < \epsilon \Leftrightarrow ... \Leftrightarrow b_1^n+...b_m^n<(\epsilon+m)^n$.
After some research I found, that the LHS can be expressed by polynomials using [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula). At this point I am afraid to be on the wrong track.

Can somebody give me a hint which respects the limitations (having only 1 lecture and it is the first task regarding sequences)?

The R-Code

```
m_max = 20
m=seq(1,m_max)
sumOfPowers=function(n){sum(m^n)}
n_max = 50
n=seq(1,n_max)
temp=sapply(n,sumOfPowers)
a_n=nthroot(temp,n)
print(data.frame(n,temp,a_n))
```

Comment: It looks like in your simulation you have $b_j=j$; you need to consider other sequences as well.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Let $b_k=\max_i b_i$, then$$a_n=b_k\sqrt[n]{\left({b_1\over b_k}\right)^n+\cdots +\left({b_m\over b_k}\right)^n}$$Now prove that $$\sqrt[n]{\left({b_1\over b_k}\right)^n+\cdots +\left({b_m\over b_k}\right)^n}\to 1$$by using $$1\le \sqrt[n]{\left({b_1\over b_k}\right)^n+\cdots +\left({b_m\over b_k}\right)^n}\le\sqrt[n]{m}$$and showing (using the definition of limit) that $$\sqrt[n]{m}\to 1$$